# What is the proper way to Windows 7/Ubuntu 10.10 Dual-Triple Boot Partitioning for Laptop OEM?

Tags: partitioning, laptop, dual-boot, gparted, oem

Hi Linux Community,
I find my self struggling with the slowness of windows OS once again.
It's Time to change with the Ubuntu 10.10 64bit for I like to use a faster Operating System.
My Hard Disk laptop has a RECOVERY and HP_TOOLS partition they are both Primary.

I Have the System Recovery DVD for Windows 64bit should anything bad happen.

Here's the layout I used with windows before:

```
* (C:) Windows 7 system partition NTFS - 284,89GB (Primary,ad Boot,Pagefile,Dump)
* HP_TOOLS system partition FAT32 - 99MB (Primary)
* (D:) RECOVERY partition NTFS - 12,90GB (Primary)
* SYSTEM partition NTFS 199MB (Primary)
```

Here's the layout I wanted to make:

```
* (C:) Windows 7 system partition NTFS - 60GB (Primary) (sda1)
* (D:) Windows DATA partition (user files) NTFS - 120GB(Primary)(sda2);wanna share with Linux
* Linux root Ext4 - 10GB (Extended)(sda3) (Ubuntu 10.10 64bit)
* Linux home Ext3 - 90GB (Extended)(sda4) (Ubuntu 10.10 64bit)
* Linux swap swap- RAM size, 3GB   (sda5)
* Linux root Ext3- 18GB (Extended) (sda6) (OpenSuse or Puppy or kubuntu)
```

Here is my New Ubuntu 10.10 64bit layout in use now:

```
* SYSTEM partition NTFS 199MB (Primary)                       (sda1)  
* (C:) Windows 7 system partition NTFS - 90GB (Primary)       (sda2)  
* (D:) Windows 7 RECOVERY partition NTFS - 12,90GB (Primary)  (sda3)
* Linux system partition EXTENDED - 195,1GB (Logical)
        * Linux root Ext4- 10GB (Extended)                    (sda4)
        * Linux swap swap- RAMx2 size, 6,1GB                  (sda5) 
        * Linux home Ext3- 179GB (Extended)                   (sda6)
```

When I installed Ubuntu,I didn't know if I could wipe all previous partitions,because of the RECOVERY partition.
So I just made the space for my extended partition with **GParted** by deleting the HP_TOOLS (Fat32).
By doing this I managed somehow to install Ubuntu 64 with Success.
And I also made the partitions for the *swap* or a *third Linux OS* as *Jordan* suggested.
But I couldn't *actually* make the partitions for the shared *NTFS*.(no option!)

Question 1: **What is the proper way to Windows 7/Ubuntu 10.10 Dual-Triple Boot Partitioning for Laptop OEM??**

Thank you in advance for your advises and suggestions and Happy New Year to All!!

Comment: "but I couldn't actually make the partitions for the swap or a third Linux OS" Why not? Why can't you add more logical partitions to your extended partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Leave your Windows Partition alone (they are fine)

**Ideally You Want to:**

1. Backup Ubuntu files you want to keep
2. Reinstall Ubuntu
3. This time make a 189GB Extended Partition
4. Within the Partition make a 188GB "`/`" partition (No it will not be harder to backup your `/home` folder, its more convenient and less messy. Consider using Deja-Dup to back up your `/home` folder)
5. Make a Swap Partition that is twice the size of your RAM, which should be 1GB as you said

NOTE:
You will **not** have trouble accessing your NTFS Windows Partitions from Ubuntu it is actually the other way around. Windows will not recognize the EXT4 Ubuntu Partition

SOLUTION:
Keep most of your personal files on your Windows Partitions like movies or documents. This way both Ubuntu and Windows can access your personal files.

Answer (score 0):

you should keep the ubuntu's home and root together and then create another ntfs partition where you would share folders between ubuntu and windows. ubuntu crashes ntfs partitions over time, this would avoid affecting core windows files. besides that you are okay since ubuntu itself doesn't need more than 3GiB for installation.

Comment: Thanks Dumb906 but if i don't make a separate home partition wouldn't be easier after if i want to backup my personal data from ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

**Safety first:**

I would first make a full backup of any data you might have on your computer. The resizing of any partition always involves somewhat dangerous operations where one's data can be corrupted or lost. Also, make sure you have the Windows recovery CD/DVD available, should anything bad happen.

If your computer can boot from USB, I would recommend first setting up a full Ubuntu on USB disk and boot your computer over USB, so you can test whether you can solve hardware issues, should you have any. I had some issue on my HP Mini, which I found first, and then solved before installing it.

Once you can confirm that indeed all major hardware components work with Ubuntu, either through more hardware drivers (open-source or closed), and that you have no major issue, except speed of the USB disk, I would be ready to actually install UBUNTU, from either a bootable CDROM or a bootable USB disk. I also think that a shared NTFS partition would be wise, so that if Ubuntu causes problems, those wil be on this shared NTFS partition, not your Windows one.

As for a third OS, I would suggest something like Fedora or Mandriva, s those are very well-known ones, but are using different system for package management and runlevels. You could also install Kubuntu, if you want to play with KDE instead of Gnome for the graphical user interface.

Comment: Thanks for your advices jfmessier.This is the first time i install 64bit version of ubuntu and i understand it might be risky with hardware compatibility.As for the third Linux OS i would like to experiment with distros like puppy or slax, so the question is more on how to partition in order to make it work. :)

Answer (score 0):

i have Laptop OEM 2 and here is what i do 
i install windows normally and i pop in my Ubuntu 10.10 CD while i`m inside windows and i install it on the second portion "D" 
that way i get -dual boot -the ability to uninstall Ubuntu easily from the control panel as a program - and it only makes a new folder in the portion i chose and names it "Ubuntu"